# Vim Regex, matches last occurrence of expression and encapsulates other occurrences as contained content?

Tags: regex, vim

Trying convert strictly the leaf variables to jason I am encountering something peculiar to me.  My regular expression is matching the last occurrence of the closing containers rather than their according closing container, most notably `author`.

Vim command:

```
%s/ \{6}<\(.*\)>\(\_.*\)<\/\1>/      "\1":"\2",
```

Before command:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
      Oberon's Legacy.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk106">
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
      <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk107">
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk108">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
      <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
      <price>6.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
      of being quantum.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk110">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
      detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk111">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
      <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
      detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
      SAX and more.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <author>Galos, Mike</author>
      <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>49.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

After command:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      "author":"Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk103">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
      <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
      society in England, the young survivors lay the 
      foundation for a new society.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk104">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
      <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
      agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
      for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
      Ascendant.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk105">
      <author>Corets, Eva</author>
      <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
      <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
      battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
      Oberon's Legacy.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk106">
      <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
      <title>Lover Birds</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
      <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
      conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk107">
      <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
      <title>Splish Splash</title>
      <genre>Romance</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
      thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk108">
      <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
      <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
      <genre>Horror</genre>
      <price>4.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
      <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
      centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk109">
      <author>Kress, Peter</author>
      <title>Paradox Lost</title>
      <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
      <price>6.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
      <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
      Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
      of being quantum.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk110">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
      <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
      detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk111">
      <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
      <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>36.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
      <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
      detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
      SAX and more.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk112">
      <author>Galos, Mike",
      "title":"Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide",
      "genre":"Computer",
      "price":"49.95",
      "publish_date":"2001-04-16",
      "description":"Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
      looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
      integrated into a comprehensive development 
      environment.",
   </book>
</catalog>
```

I don't understand why this happening and how to express the first occurrence of the closing container in my expression? i.e. `%s/ \{6}<\(.*\)>\(\_.*\)<\/\1\{FIRST_OCCURRENCE}>/      "\1":"\2",`

NOTE: The preceeding is pertinent [this VimGolf challenge](http://vimgolf.com/challenges/50ea3ca82bf6290002000040).

PLEASE ALSO NOTE: VimGolf is intended to help people learn much more than it is intended to be a serious competition.  As it says on every challenge:

> The best way to learn is to practice. Below, you will find some of the
>   solutions other golfers have entered. To unlock higher ranked
>   solutions, submit your own entry which does as well or better than the
>   solutions you can currently see - climb the ladder!
>
> Check out these helpful resources to improve your Vim skills... Game on.

Please don't vote me down for trying to learn.

Comment: I think the idea of VimGolf is trying to solve the problems yourself...

Comment: @IngoKarkat VimGolf is intended more for learning than to be a serious competition.  The site shows you other peoples solutions within range of your own score and allows you to submit identical solutions.  If you actually read my question, you would see I'm trying to understand why my expression isn't doing what I want it do.  How does trying to expand my understanding of Vim justify you voting me down?

Comment: @romainl Please read my other comments.

Comment: @rudolph9, VimGolf *is* a competition. You can enter it with the hope of learning a thing or two but you are still taking part in a (fierce) competition. Asking random people on the net to help you with your golfing is just like asking random people to do your homework for you. It's cheating and it's something that is collectivelly frowned upon around here. If you hadn't mentioned VimGolf you'd have had better responce.

Comment: @romainl VimGolf allows submission of exact duplicates solutions.  Not only that, they show you lower stroke submissions than your own.  If someone wanted, they could submit the displayed one better solution over and over until they have tied the leader.  How can you consider VimGolf a "fierce" competition?

Comment: Because of what you just described *and* because the lowest keystrokes solutions are often impressive.

Comment: @romainl If it makes you feel better, I won't submit any entries for this challenge. But, no where in the rules does it state 'do not consult others'.   While the rules say "_Refrain_ from copy/paste, reading in the solution (:read), or using external tools", I wasn't trying steal someone else's work. I  just wanted to know why my expression matches the last occurrence rather than the first and I'm kinda offended I got down voted for it...

Comment: Agreed, the lowest keystroke solutions are impressive and I'm sorry if anything came off like I was belittling those submissions.

Comment: Call it pride or whatever you want but, if I was participating in VimGolf, there's *no way in all hell* I'd ask anybody to help me. Whatever your real motive was, the simple mention of "VimGolf" raised a big flag. The same would've happened with "assignment".

Comment: @romainl I respect where you are coming from but putting personal feelings aside, will you reconsider your downvote.  Considering that no rules of VimGolf were broken, my question is fairly well composed for stackoverflow, and I had the integrity to site my sources, will you please reconsider your downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `\_.*` is greedy, meaning it will search everything until the last occurrence. An alternative might be to use `\{-}` instead of `*`, which is the non-greedy alternative.

Comment: I really appreciate that you took the time to read my question, rather than seeing the name 'VimGolf' and deciding to call my question cheating and voting me down.